# Using A String Value As the Name of a Function to Be Called

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
var MyObject = function(prop) {
  this.property = prop;
};

var stringVar = 'MyObject';

var myObject = new stringVar(1);  // This doesn't work.

assertTrue(myObject.property === 1);
```

I know that this will work:

```
var myObject = new window[stringVar](1);
```

but I was wondering if there was a more context neutral way of accomplishing it.

As a side note: I am obviously trying to avoid using `eval()`.

Comment: I believe what you have, is an acceptable way of doing it. What do you mean by "context neutral"?

Comment: what do you mean with context-neutral? You'll always need to have at least some idea of where the function is located, wether it's on the window object, or somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry: environment neutral.  Code that would work in environments others than a web browser.

Comment: Just namespace and maintain a reference to that scope. That way you can always call the function. This should be sufficiently environment-neutral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known limitation in Javascript. There's no way to reference functions by string in a context-neutral way. What you have is all you can do.

So, if you were to have all this within a closure, it wouldn't work. Your only option would be to have your constructor as a method of another object:

```
var constructors = {
    MyObject: function(prop) {
        this.property = prop;
    }
}

var stringVar = 'MyObject';

var myObject = new constructors[stringVar](1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a namespace so you always know the hierarchy, e.g. the following will work on a desktop .js file run with the windows scripting host (where there is no `window`)

```
var MyNameSpace = {};

MyNameSpace.MyObject = function(prop) {
  this.property = prop;
};

var stringVar = 'MyObject';
var myObject = new MyNameSpace[stringVar](123);
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you want:

```
var obj = {"myObject": function(prop) {this.property = prop; return this;},
           "MySecondObject": "probably second function"
          },
    str = "myObject";
var myChildObj = obj[str]("test");
alert(myChildObj.property);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deathApril/KU8Cf/1/)